# step plot using holoviews bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I'm trying to add two step plots to the same Bokeh plot. Each step plot has different x values though, so the `Step` function in the `bkcharts` package doesnt work. I wanted to overlay two single `Step` charts produced by the `bkcharts` package, but it seems that you can't create a step chart with `holoviews`. Is there an easy workaround?

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.charts import Step
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,3,5,7], 'value': [3,4,1,3]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [2,4,6,9], 'value': [2,1,4,2]})


step1 = Step(data1, x='time', y='value')
step2 = Step(data2, x='time', y='value')

bk.show(Step(data1, x='time', y='value'))
bk.show(Step(data2, x='time', y='value'))
```

I would like to do something like `step1 * step2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HoloViews does let you do a step chart, using options to the Curve element.  See the example in the [Gallery](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Curve.html#Interpolation):

```
%%opts Curve [width=600] NdOverlay [legend_position='right']
hv.NdOverlay({interp: hv.Curve(points[::8])(plot=dict(interpolation=interp))
              for interp in ['linear', 'steps-mid', 'steps-pre', 'steps-post']})
```

[image]

You can do the same with a regular Overlay (the `*` operator) too; the key is to set the `interpolation` option to one of the available types of steps.

Comment: Here's a better link, from Philipp Rudiger, to an example that's a matching copy of the Bokeh example: http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/step_chart.html#bokeh-gallery-step-chart

Comment: How do you add an x coordinate to the holoviews curve?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the holoviews curve already *has* x coordinates?